# No GWT page loaded in Opera under Linux

Tags: linux, gwt, opera

I was testing compatibility of various browsers on various platforms with my GWT application.

In Opera 12.16 for Linux x86-64 there is no GWT application displayed once the page has finished loading. I cannot see any errors in Console or Errors sections of developer tools.

I tested if this is also case in other GWT pages and I tried

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html
and
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Mail/Mail.html

with the same result.

This problem is however not in Windows 7 64 bit (Operat version 22).

Does anyone else have these problems? Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In 2.6.0, GWT disabled the opera permutation since Opera decided to adopt webkit in new versions of the browser (Opera-13). So if you run a modern version of opera it picks up safari permutation, otherwise you have to enable opera permutation by yourself.

In the other hand, Opera announced to stop linux development in Dec-2013, so your version seems to be running the old engine

So your problem is that your opera version is not running webkit, enable opera permutation in your module.gwt.xml file:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" values="ie8,ie9,opera" />
```

Comment: "In the other hand, Opera announced to stop linux development in Dec-2013, so your version seems to be running the old engine" --- what, what announcement where? They just shipped a pre-release version of Chropera for Linux, and to my knowledge 12 is still receiving security updates on all platforms.

Comment: I have not used opera in linux for a while, but I read this some time ago: http://beta.slashdot.org/story/197583 . Based on their [download page](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux) they don't have an official release of opera linux using webkit, but they seem to have a [developer release](http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/06/opera-24-linux-released-developer-stream/) now. But anyway, and focusing on the GWT question, the way to use opera 12 is enabling the legacy opera permutation.